# Why does RStudio show the manually knitted pdf wrong?

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

I'm running the latest RStudio (0.97.551) and R (3.0.1) version on Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.4.

I have the following two files:
test.Rnw

```
\documentclass{article}

<<set-options, echo=FALSE>>=
 options(replace.assign=TRUE)
 opts_chunk$set(external=TRUE, cache=TRUE, echo=FALSE, fig=TRUE)
 read_chunk('chunks.R')
@

\begin{document}
\section{Graphics}

<<chart, fig.height=4>>=
@

\end{document}
```

and chunks.R

```
## @knitr chart
library(ggplot2, quietly=TRUE)
Sys.sleep(3)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))  + geom_point(aes(size = qsec)) +
   labs(title ="title with umlauts ä")
p
sessionInfo()
```

When knitting this document in RStudio everything is fine:

[image: generated with RStudio]

Now I clear the cache and knit the document manually from a script running the commands:

```
export TEXINPUTS=$TEXINPUTS:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/share/texmf/tex/latex/
/usr/bin/Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit(\"test.Rnw\")"
pdflatex ./test.tex
```

Everything is still fine.

But then I don't clear the cache and knit again in RStudio. the PDF-viewer of RStudio now displays the chart as follows:

[image: Regenerated with RStudio after chunks are generated manually]

Mac OS X Preview shows both pdfs fine. The only difference in sessionInfo() I can see is the order of the base packages.

Has anyone an idea why RStudio shows the graphic wrong?

I don't know how to share the two pdfs. So if anyone needs them and tells me how to share them, I'll do it.

TIA,
JW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RStudio sets `grDevices::pdf.options(useDingbats = FALSE)` before it calls `knitr` (see the panel `Compile PDF` which contains the log), and the option `useDingbats` is `TRUE` by default in R. RStudio's built-in PDF viewer does not honor the Dingbats font, so the circles (solid points) were broken in its PDF viewer when `useDingbats = TRUE`. See `?pdf` for more information.

You should not use RStudio's PDF viewer to view the PDF generated *outside* of RStudio by yourself. There are other good choices in `Tools -> Options -> Sweave -> PDF preview`, such as `Sumutra PDF` under Windows, and `evince` under Linux. I have no idea about Mac OS X, though (at least you can use the default viewer of the system, I believe).