# Compile Rnw to tex

Tags: r, tex, sweave

**Code**

hello.Rnw:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\end{document}
```

Commands:

```
rnwfile <- system.file("Sweave", "hello.Rnw", package = "utils")
Sweave(rnwfile)
```

Output:

> Error in SweaveReadFile(file, syntax, encoding = encoding) : 
>     no Sweave file with name ‘’ found

**Question**

What is the problem here? Using another more complex file outputs the same. If I add to Sweave() only the path of the file it works for hello.Rnw but not for more complex files. Then the output is: "Error: ‘test.Rnw’ is not ASCII and does not declare an encoding".

Answer (score 2):

The `system.file()` function is for locating files that are installed as part of an R package. For example, if you want to run Sweave examples that come with R, they have to be the ones that are actually provided, e.g.

```
list.files(system.file("Sweave",package="utils"))
## [1] "example-1.Rnw"     "Sweave-test-1.Rnw"
Sweave(system.file("Sweave","example-1.Rnw",package="utils"))
```

works fine.  (You may have been confused by the `?Sweave` documentation, which uses this syntax - it's not a necessary part of the Sweave workflow, just used there to retrieve an example input file.)

If you want to run `Sweave()` **on your own `.Rnw` files**, you need to make sure that they are in your working directory (or specify the full path); see `?setwd`/`?getwd`.

We would need to see `test.Rnw` in order to know what the problem is there.

If you're not attached to Sweave, I would strongly recommend looking into the `knitr` package: it does the same things as Sweave, but (IMO) better.  (It's also very well documented.)

Comment: The purpose is to create the command which is done by the button COMPILE PDF.

Comment: I will tell you if I have any other outputs. I will try

Comment: You could have asked that question directly ... `knitr::knit2pdf("myfile")`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591487/difference-compile-pdf-button-in-rstudio-vs-knit-and-knit2pdf

Comment: Now Im using Sweave2knitr() to create knitr file and then knit2pdf(), but output is ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!. Using "COMPILE PDF" over Sweave Plugin when Rnw file is open everything works fine

Comment: Now the processing works but the PDF-output looks terrible.

Comment: it's going to be really, really hard to remotely troubleshoot your R/Sweave/LaTeX setup ...

Comment: with `knit2pdf` the output looks ugly.

Comment: I sympathize, but there's really not enough information here to help you.  If you still need help and can't get any local help (which would probably be the easiest thing at this point), you should ask another question that carefully details the steps you have taken so far. An image of your "ugly" `knit2pdf` output would be helpful. (Just to clarify, clicking on the "Compile PDF" button *does* give reasonable output?)

Comment: Clicking on the "Compile PDF" creates an structured and readable output. Tomorrow I will try to give you an example output, to understand the problem of the output.

Comment: After trying I'm getting other outputs: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603194/error-compiling-rnw-to-tex