# Error compiling Rnw to tex

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I had a problem using function `Sweave`. It seemed to be an encoding problem because I did not specify any encoding like: \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}.

Now using button "Compile PDF" works -> PDF is generated and everythink is OK. But I'm getting 30 warnings and 18 badboxes.

Using function `Sweave` to generate first the tex file fails with this message:

```
Error:  chunk 4 (label = t4)
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
In addition: There were 31 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

So one warning more than before.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Problem solved. The problem was using .. for the paths setted by the R code. Using complete path with "C:\\Users\\test\\" instead of "..\\test\\" solved the problem.

Comment: if you've solved your own problem, you should either delete it or post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem was created by using .. for the paths setted by the R code. Using complete path with "C:\Users\test\" instead of "..\test\" solved the problem. So the code from folder "test" couldnt be loaded because the Sweave-Function used other paths (like WORKING DIRECTORY).