# accessing Global Environment dataframe in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I have a dataframe in R called `df`. This is available across all .r files in the R session. I want to *knitr* some of the results from this dataframe into a .Rmd file. I'm using the following code:

````
```{r}
names(df)
```
````

If I highlight and run the line: `names(df)` within the .Rmd file, it correctly prints out the names of `df`: `[1] "ISIN" "CF"   "DATE"`. But if I click on `Knit HTML`, it outputs in HTML:

```
## NULL
```

How do I get a .Rmd document to access Global Environment variables?

Comment: I'm not seeing a question, but your observation is correct. Knitting from the console with `knit()`, `knit2html()`, etc., is done within the current R session. Knitting via the RStudio hotkey is done in a fresh R session so it doesn't have access to the global environment from your active session. One way around it is to `save()` objects out and have them `load()` them in your knitr document.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it: `Knit HTML` button driven .Rmd files cannot access the Global Environment

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591487/difference-compile-pdf-button-in-rstudio-vs-knit-and-knit2pdf