# Knitr in Rstudio - decoupled environment from the console?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Knitting a markdown script, especially if it includes processing of large data sets, can take some time. I noticed, however, that the R console stays available during the knitting of an R notebook.

Does that mean that the environments of the Rstudio console and the knitting process are separated from another, no danger of cross-effects?

Comment: Depends on whether you use one of "the buttons" or call `knit` (or one of its friends) directly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591487/difference-compile-pdf-button-in-rstudio-vs-knit-and-knit2pdf

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I find the explanations in the linked thread confusing. I am using the Knit2html command from the Rstudio GUI (i.e. the "button"), and it seems to work in parallel to my console session.

Comment: That's correct, the "Knit HTML" button envokes a new environment. [This](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552056-Using-Sweave-and-knitr) is the relevant link from the linked question (see the paragraph under the first picture).

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help!