# Using packrat libraries with knitr and the rstudio compile PDF button

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, packrat

As explained by Yihui Xie in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591487/difference-compile-pdf-button-in-rstudio-vs-knit-and-knit2pdf), when one uses the Compile PDF button of the RStudio IDE to produce a PDF from a .Rnw file, `knit()` uses the `globalenv()` of a new R session. Is there a way that this new R session would use the `packrat` libraries of my project (even the version of `knitr` included in my `packrat` libraries) instead of my personal user libraries to ensure a maximum level of reproducibility? I guess that the new R session would have to be linked to the project itself, but I don't know how to do this efficiently.

I know I could directly use the `knit()` function instead of the Compile PDF button and, that way, `knit()` would use my current `globalenv()`, but I don't like this solution since it's less reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

I think I got the problem myself, but I want to share with others who could confirm I'm right, and possibly help improve my solution.

My specific problem is that my .Rnw file is in a sub-directory of my whole project. When the Compile PDF button creates a new R session, it is created in this sub-directory, thus not finding the `.Rprofile` file that would initialize `packrat`. I think the easiest solution would be to create a `.Rprofile` file in my subdirectory which contains

```
temp <- getwd()
setwd("..")
source("packrat/init.R")
setwd(temp)
rm(temp)
```

I have to change the working directory at the project level before `source("packrat/init.R")` because the file itself refers to the directory...

Anybody can see a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

P.,

I don't know if this solution works for even the `knitr` package, but I am 99% sure it works for all other packages as it seems to for me.

(I believe) I have a very similar problem. I have my ***project*** folder, but my working directory has always been the ***sub folder*** where my ***.rnw*** file is located, in a subdirectory of my ***project*** folder.

The link to [Yihiu Xie's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591487/difference-compile-pdf-button-in-rstudio-vs-knit-and-knit2pdf) answer was very helpful.

Originally I wanted a project folder such as:

```
project-a/
               working/
                        data/
                                  datas.csv
                        analysis/
                                  library.R
                                  rscripts.R
                        rnw/
                                  report.rnw
                        child/
                                  preamble.rnw
                        packrat/
```

But I'm not sure if that is possible with `packrat` when my `R library()` calls are not in the working directory and `packrat` cannot parse the .rnw file (I call the library.R file from a chunck using `source()` in my ***.rnw*** file). A few notes:

- I wanted to use a ***.Rproj*** file to open the project and have ***project-a/working*** as the working directory

  - If this was true then `packrat` can find the ***library.R*** script
  - But the ***.rnw*** file still defaults to its own working directory when compiling
- I thought an ***.Rprofile*** with `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "..")` would work but I don't think it works for latex commands like `input\`, it defaults back to the directory containing the ***.rnw*** file

  - I thought this was insufficient because then you have two working directories, one for your `r chunks` and one for your latex!

Since ***.rnw*** always sets the working directory, I put my ***library.R*** script in the same directory as my ***.rnw*** file which creates the `packrat` folder in ***project-a/working/rnw***. I am 99% sure this works because when I created the `packrat` folder in the ***project-a/working/rnw*** folder WITHOUT relocating the ***library.R*** file it received an error that no packages could be found and I could not compile the ***.rnw*** file.

```
project-a/
               working/
                        data/
                                  datas.csv
                        analysis/
                                  rscripts.R
                        rnw/
                                  report.rnw
                                  library.R
                                  packrat/
                        child/
                                  preamble.rnw
```

Again, unless I am overlooking something or misunderstanding which packages are being used, this seems to have worked for me. Disclaimer here that I am relatively new to `packrat`.