# R Knit Markdown code chunk: "object not found"

Tags: r, rstudio, markdown, r-markdown, knitr

New to markdown and knit, so...
In RStudio, this markdown code does well

````
## 'r': razão entre opções
```{r}
round(apply(rst0[,c('rstQ','rstV','rstMkt','rstMkt2','rstAntiMkt')],2,mean),3)
```
````

```
  rstQ       rstV     rstMkt    rstMkt2 rstAntiMkt 
81.408    111.098      0.012      0.007      0.005
```

But when I click knit button, I get error:

```
Line 20 Error in apply(rst0[,c('rstQ','rstV','rstMkt','rstMkt2','rstAntiMkt')], : object 'rst0' not found Calls: <Anonimous> ... withCallingHandlers  -> withVisible -> eval -> eval  -> apply
```

But `knit('../gap.Rmd')` successfully generates the `gap.md` file.

Comment: is `rst0` created in the rmarkdown file - if not the code won't be able to find it

Comment: @RichardTelford, all variables must be created in markdown file? Why can markdown find `summary(cars)`? Is it not possible to pass `rst0`to code chunk? Why `knit(..)` works? Sorry for my so little knowledge.

Comment: `cars` is a built-in R object so it is always available. The knit button renders the rmarkdown in a new environment - no objects are present. knit(...) will run the code from the existing environment so objects can be found. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591487/difference-compile-pdf-button-in-rstudio-vs-knit-and-knit2pdf

Comment: I ended up putting an `{r ini, include=F}` chunk that loads the data needed. It seems a good practice.