# R Markdown render fails knit with mlogit, object not found, but code chunks work

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have done a basic search around the site (e.g. [R Knit Markdown code chunk: "object not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243555/r-knit-markdown-code-chunk-object-not-found)), but I don't think I have found anything that fixes my problem, or at least explains why my problem occurs.

There are only a few code chunks in my .rmd which come quite verbatim from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/e1mlogit.html

The first is to load data

```
rm(list = ls())
library(mlogit)
data("Heating", package = "mlogit")
H <- mlogit.data(Heating, shape = "wide", choice = "depvar", varying = c(3:12))
```

Then I fit the model, but I use `ref_level_var` instead of any specific string `"gr"`

```
ref_level_var <- "gr"
mc <- mlogit(formula = depvar ~ ic + oc, data = H, reflevel = ref_level_var)
```

The odd part comes when I try

```
head(predict(mc, newdata = H))
```

Now because I require my files to be knit to two different formats (solution via [Knit one markdown file to two output files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39662365/knit-one-markdown-file-to-two-output-files/53280491#53280491)), I use the following `knit` in my header for the .rmd

```
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
  rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding, output_format = c("html_document", "pdf_document"))})
```

However, this results in the following error

```
Error in model.frame.mFormula(formula = depvar ~ ic + oc, data = structure(list(: object 'ref_level_var' not found
```

Obviously, it seems that somehow `ref_level_var` is not visible to the knitting session, despite there being a `ref_level_var <- "gr"` line somewhere. Why does this error occur, and how can I fix it?

Note that the error is very odd, because replacing the whole `knit` line with `output: html_document` results in no errors.