# Caret doparallel in Rmarkdown: Missing verbose info when using render()

Tags: r, r-caret, doparallel

I have the following simple example `Rmarkdown` document (test.Rmd):

````
---
title: "Test Knit Caret Paralell VerboseIter"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

require(caret)
require(doParallel)


```

## data

```{r data}

set.seed(998)
training <- twoClassSim()

```

## model

```{r fitmodel}
fitControl <- trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 3,
  repeats = 2,
  verboseIter = T)


ncores <- detectCores()-1

cl <<- makePSOCKcluster(ncores, verbose = TRUE, outfile = "")
registerDoParallel(cl)

set.seed(825)
Fit <- train(Class ~ ., 
             data = training, 
             method = "nnet", 
             trControl = fitControl,
             trace = FALSE
)
stopCluster(cl)
registerDoSEQ()
```

## results

```{r results}
Fit
```
````

I have several options to run this code or knit the document

1. Use 'Run all chuncks' in Rstudio
2. Use `Knit` button in Rstudio
3. `Knit` document with `render("test.Rmd")`

The following happens

1. No info gets printed in output or console on iterations
2. Info gets printed in the `R markdown` panel
3. No info gets printed in console

In the project I work on I want to `knit` the document with different parameters, so I want to use the last option. However I also want to see the progress on fitting the model. Therefor I want to use option 3.

How can I get the info of the iterations printed in console when the documents are rendered?

This is the expected output I want to see:

```
+ Fold1.Rep1: size=1, decay=0e+00 
+ Fold1.Rep1: size=3, decay=0e+00 
+ Fold1.Rep1: size=5, decay=0e+00 
- Fold1.Rep1: size=1, decay=0e+00 
+ Fold1.Rep1: size=1, decay=1e-01 
- Fold1.Rep1: size=3, decay=0e+00 
+ Fold1.Rep1: size=3, decay=1e-01 
- Fold1.Rep1: size=5, decay=0e+00 
+ Fold1.Rep1: size=5, decay=1e-01 
- Fold1.Rep1: size=1, decay=1e-01 
+ Fold1.Rep1: size=1, decay=1e-04 
- Fold1.Rep1: size=3, decay=1e-01 
+ Fold1.Rep1: size=3, decay=1e-04 
- Fold1.Rep1: size=1, decay=1e-04 
etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may produce what you're looking for, adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591487/difference-compile-pdf-button-in-rstudio-vs-knit-and-knit2pdf), it essentially replicates when you use the `knit` button in `rstudio`, which produces the verbose from `train`, however using this method you should be able to pass in `parameters` to `render`. Just change the path to the `wd` of your `rmd` file

```
owd = setwd("path/to/your-Rmd-directory")
system2("Rscript", c("-e", shQuote("library(rmarkdown); render('test.Rmd')"),
            system2("html", "test.html"),
            setwd(owd)))
```

Comment: It works. But is there any way to stop de proces? When I stop in Rstudio the process seems to continue in the background.

Comment: @Wietze314 Using the `stop` in Rstudio or  the `Esc` key works for me. You could also set a `timeout`

Comment: I used `stop` in Rstudio, and it looked like it stopped. But when I look at task manager, all cores are still running on 100%. Only when I manually shut down all R sessions in task manager it really stops.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `knit_hook` at the top of the Rmd file to capture the console outputs and print them while rendering.

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
print_output <- function(x, options) {
  cat(x)
  return(x)
}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = print_output)
```
````

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried your solution, but it kind of works, but the output intended for the markdown file, gets printed to the console only. How can I make sure, the output intended for the markdown is printed in the output file (too).

Comment: @Wietze314 Edited. If the function returns the input, it will also be printed in the knitted file. `output` needs to be changed to `chunk` to make the fonts consistent. See https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/.

Comment: I also noticed that the output is printed only when the `chunk` code has been fully executed. So the progress during learning is not printed, which I wanted to track.